# Apache 2.4.7 mod-mono won't install ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mono, mod-mono

Recently reinstalled my computer with `Ubuntu 14.04`.

This pc is to be used to develop `ASP.NET` mono applications.

So I installed the latest 3.12.0 version of Mono.

Also installed Apache2 (2.4.7 is the latest).

Last thing is to install Mod_Mono. This is where it fails.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-mono : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried to install `apache2.2-common` but that does not exist, there is only a `apache2.2-bin`. I installed that and it still did not solve my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2.2-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  apache2-bin:i386 apache2:i386 apache2-data apache2-bin apache2

E: Package 'apache2.2-common' has no installation candidate
```

Any suggestions to what I can do so I can host my Mono application through apache2?

Comment: Not sure, thats why I am commenting but it looks like mod-mono depends on Apache2.2-common and you've installed Apache 2.4.7. You may need to go down an Apache release. Also Mod_Mono is an Apache 1.3/2.0/2.2/2.4 module. Another reason it may not work with Apache2.4.7

Comment: How do you install 2.2? I had a good look and can't find a solution. I did an `apt-cache` but there is no 2.2 version.

Comment: Apt is only going to get supported packages. On Ubuntu 14.04 you might have to manually install Apache 2.2 or up to release 2.4. That will work fine and will install the supporting so libraries like common and bin. This all depends on how you installed Apache

Comment: Yeh tried installing an older version but had no luck. Apache would just fail when it starts after it was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by installing Apache 2.2.22.

Had a bit of trouble doing that, but finally installed it running this command.

`sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2.2-common=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2.2-bin=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 apache2-mpm-worker=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7`

Note: you need to add the precise repository to your software sources, else you won't have the package available to install.

Comment: You need to add a compatibility repository for mod_mono to work with Apache 2.4: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#modmono-ubuntu-1310-and-later-debian-80-and-later

Comment: Think I did add that, and it still complained, ill try set up another box and follow instructions on this link again to see if it works. Thank you btw.